# blank tables inner join - cross join

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Does inner join of two empty tables lead to cross join?

Comment: By "blank tables", I suppose you mean empty tables. An inner join on 2 empty tables won't produce any rows. 0 x 0 = 0

Comment: Blank tables? You mean empty tables? Well, from empty tables you get an empty result set, no matter whether inner joined, outer joined or cross joined.

Comment: you will get empty result set even if one table is empty in an inner join.

Comment: So I am being accused of using no join conditions (and I am using join conditions) which is leading to cross join. And the only explanation I can come up with is that both tables are empty (yes by blank tables, I meant empty tables :) )

Comment: As mentioned, from an empty result set you cannot tell whether there was a cross join or not. So if someone says you are cross joining records, they obviously see rows to draw this conclusion. Maybe your join criteria is incomplete. Show your query and the table definitions.

Comment: A cross join is an inner join without any join conditions. Will have the same result for empty tables. (As well as outer join, union etc...)

Comment: Show us your query! (And also add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia: [Cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join)

> CROSS JOIN returns the Cartesian product of rows from tables in the
>   join.
>   In other words, it will produce rows which combine each row from the
>   first table with each row from the second table.[1]

Taking the above into consideration, the cross join of two empty tables will produce an empty resultset.
The join of two empty tables also will produce an empty result. Because according to the definition [the join is a speciall case of cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join)

> The result of the join can be defined as the outcome of first taking
>   the Cartesian product (or Cross join) of all rows in the tables
>   (combining every row in table A with every row in table B) and then
>   returning all rows which satisfy the join predicate.

so yes - one can say that the inner join of two empty tables lead to cross join